Format of "R repository file"
From https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/utils/html/setRepositories.html

The default list of known repositories is stored in the file ‘R_HOME/etc/repositories’. That file can be edited for a site, or a user can have a personal copy in the file pointed to by the environment variable R_REPOSITORIES, or if this is unset, NULL or does not exist, in ‘HOME/.R/repositories’, which will take precedence.

It's not clear what this format this file is supposed to be in. Running
$ cat /etc/R/repositories 
## The fields here are tab-delimited: there is a row name
## menu_name    is the name to be used in setRepositories()
## URL      is the base URL (see R-admin.texi)
## default  is whether this should be a default choice
## source, win.binary, mac.binary   indicate if the corresponding type is present
##
## BioC entries are version-specific, with %v getting expanded to the
## value of the environment variable 'R_BIOC_VERSION' or, if unset, to the
## BioC version associated with the current R version.
## Also, %bm is substituted from the setting of getOption("BioC_mirror")
##
menu_name   URL default source  win.binary  mac.binary
CRAN    CRAN    @CRAN@  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
BioCsoft    "BioC software" %bm/packages/%v/bioc    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
BioCann "BioC annotation"   %bm/packages/%v/data/annotation FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
BioCexp "BioC experiment"   %bm/packages/%v/data/experiment FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
CRANextra   CRAN (extras)   https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
#Omegahat   Omegahat    http://www.omegahat.net/R   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
R-Forge R-Forge https://R-Forge.R-project.org   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
rforge.net  rforge.net  https://www.rforge.net  FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE

but changing that file or creating a modified version of that file in $HOME/.R/repositories appears to not change the output of getOption("repos").
Have I misunderstood what the file is for (and changing the contents of the files is detectable somewhere else), or have I used the wrong format, and are there better docs somewhere else?
